# How to achieve two function signatures for `for loop unzip`

Tags: python, for-loop

Following snippet gives my intention of unzipping `t1, t2, t3` or `t1, t2` depending upon the task. I know such `if-else` on `for` statement doesn't exist but I am wondering is there a workaround for this. Any help or clarification questions are welcome.

```
def func(task, t1, t2, t3):

    if task == 'abc': # t3=None for this case
        for t1, t2 in zip(t1, t2):
            // do something
    else:
        for t1, t2, t3 in zip(t1, t2, t3):
            // do something

if task == 'abc':
    t3 = None
func(task, t1, t2, t3)
```

Is there a way we can write a single for loop statement and then unzip the parameters inside of the for loop depending upon the `task` value. The problem is that when the third parameters is `None`, it throws the error: `TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration when` task==abc`. I want to have a common of` do something`.

Comment: this is not valid python .... please post valid python with expected output and input you could just do `for items in zip(*something)`

Comment: that's what I tried to do. But it gives me this error: `TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration` when `args.task==abc` since the third argument is `None`.

Comment: no one knows what your trying to do from this example(or at a minimum I don't) ... kwargs is a dict so you cannot unpack it with *kwargs in any circumstance ... why are you calling zip? args is argparse.args? or something else?

Comment: let me make it more readable

Comment: Are you sure you want `**kwargs` rather than `*args`?

Comment: When you call it with `args.task = 'abc'` you shouldn't pass the `t3` argument.

Comment: You shouldn't pass `t3` when using `args.task = 'abc'`

Comment: i dont understand the senario where calling `func(t1,t2,t3)` would not throw an error since this only expects one positional argument and then keywords

Comment: I made edit to the question, does it look more readable now?

Comment: can you show us what you are actually passing in for t1 and t2 and t3 and what you are expecting as output? its slightly more readable ... and at least its valid python now I think

Comment: t1, t2, t3 are lists of strings/ numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.repeat()` to provide a default third list for `zip()` that produces a continuous stream of a default value.

```
def func(task, a1, a2, a3 = None):
    if a3 is None:
        a3 = itertools.repeat(None)
    for t1, t2, t3 in zip(a1, a2, a3):
        // do someting
```

Comment: zip(something,something,None) would be an error still i think ...  presumably t1 and t2 are strings ... maybe t3="" would work ... i don't understand the expected behaviour from OP yet

Comment: `args[2]` shouldn't be `None` when they're doing the `else` task.

Comment: t1, t2, t3 are lists

Comment: @barmar i dont know that that is guaranteed from the logic or sample provided but I can believe that it holds true

Comment: My question is: can `// do something` be a common area irrespective of whether the third argument is `None`?

Comment: I don't see how, since there won't be a t3 when `args.task` is `abc`. Is there a default value that could be used for `t3` in that case?

Comment: Why not? It can be a common area (and it is a huge block) and that's why I don't want to have too lengthy code structure. Inside of that block, I will have checks again for the third argument whenever I want to use.

Comment: Unless there's a default value for t3, how can you use code that depends on t3 in the loop that only sets t1 and t2?

Comment: Anyway, if you want to use the same code, put it in another function and call that function from both loops.

Comment: For 1st comment, I would use `t3` only when it is available and I do have check for that inside the block.
For 2nd comment, I won't say it is a bad idea.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it in a relatively clean way

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what the problem is with your existing code, but you could rearrange it like this:

```
def func(task, *args):
    for items in zip(*args):
        if task == "abc":
            item1, item2 = items
            # do something with them
        else:
            item1, item2, item3 = items
            # do something with these
```

or this:

```
def func(task, t1, t2, t3=None):
    if task == "abc":
        lists = [t1, t2]
    else:
        lists = [t1, t2, t3]
    for items in zip(*lists):
    #... as above
```

or you could use an iterable that endlessly yields `None` as the default argument:

```
 from itertools import repeat

 def func(task, t1, t2, t3=repeat(None)):
     for item1, item2, item3 in zip(t1, t2, t3):
         # Now item3 will always be None if t3 is not specified
```

Comment: Perfect, this makes so much sense